# Cheap software/app to publish interactive graphs (like Excel's Pivot Charts) online

Tags: data-visualization, charts

A dynamic chart where the user can apply filters on the categorical variables.

I would also like the related database to remain inaccessible to the user.

An [example](http://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&hl=en_US&dl=en_US#!ctype=l&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=h&met_y=children_out_of_school&fdim_y=education_level:2&scale_y=lin&ind_y=false&rdim=region&idim=region:EAS:ECS:LCN:MEA:NAC&ifdim=region&hl=en_US&dl=en_US&ind=false) of such chart.

Comment: @Silverfish It can be, definitely, as it asks for recommendations for a web-based visualization software

Comment: Your example is on Google charts. What's wrong with using Google charts?

Comment: What type of charts do you require? And in what format is your data (SQL, Mongo/Counch, JSON, etc)? Must the solution be free, or do you have a budget? The more information that you can give us, the more likely that we can help you.

Answer (score 3):

The [Shiny app](http://shiny.rstudio.com/) by the folks from RStudio helps you do that. It is a web application framework for your R analytics and code.

It helps you apply requisite filters which you can define, and you can decide on including the database access permissions too.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to what Dawny mentioned above, there is also [Plot.ly](http://plot.ly/) which you can use exactly like you would use Excel online. There is also a [Powerpoint add-on](https://store.office.com/plotly-charts-WA104379485.aspx?assetid=WA104379485) to have the interactive graphs inside powerpoint presentations. Just in case you don't know, or don't want to learn `R` (though you should, because Shiny is awesome).

And for the sake of completeness, the graph that you linked above was created using Google Charts, which you can use from `R` and share on ShinyApps through RStudio really easily. The package is called [GoogleVis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/googleVis.pdf).

Also if you're interested in learning about about interactive visualization in `R`, I recently gave a talk on that subject, here are the [slides](https://ccole.shinyapps.io/PTP_presentation) and the [RMarkdown](https://github.com/Chris1221/talks) can be found in the github repo.

Comment: Yeah, Plot.ly is also a lovely tool. I have been using it since some time now. So, I can definitely vouch for it.

Comment: @Dawny33 Definitely! I met some of the staff at a conference and they were lovely people. I think at the time they had 16 people working in their Montreal office. Glad to see it getting more exposure.

Answer (score 1):

Visually, that graph reminds me of [flotplot](http://www.flotcharts.org/), which is a javascript tool for plotting graphs which can be interactive. (Incidentally, I think they look much better than Excel graphs too.)

You can program any filtering routine you want, but you will probably have to do the implementation yourself. At least, I'm not aware of a connection between flotplot and an extensive math library like R.

Flotplot only sends the user the data needed to plot the curves, so users won't be able to access the whole database at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Web Pivot Table](http://webpivottable.com). It is totally web based and run inside browsers and it has full functionalities as excel pivot table.

There are [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) and [Documents](http://webpivottable.com/documents) show you how to use it. Installation is quite simple and user interface is pretty intuitive.

It creates pivot table and pivot chart synchronizedly and support OLAP cube pivot as well.

It has two editions. Free edition is free for anyone or any company. Professional edition can be embedded into any other applications or software and need to purchase a license.

Comment: Are you somehow involved with this product? All your posts on this site have just been about this one. If so, you must disclose your relation.